# C parsing command line arguments, binary to decimal converter error

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-errors, binary, decimal

below is a slice of code that parses different command line arguments. The goal is to create a program that will allow you to convert decimal numbers to binary, vice versa. The code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned long long str_to_ull(char* str,int base)
{
    int i;
    unsigned long long ull = 0;
    for (i=0; str[i] != 0; i++)
{
    ull *= base;
    ull += str[i]-'0';
}
return ull;
}

void print_ull(unsigned long long ull,int base)
{
    if (ull/base > 0)
        print_ull(ull/base,base);
    printf("%d",ull%base);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    char* OPTION;
    char* SIZE  ;
    char* NUMBER;

    unsigned long long number = 0;

    if (argc < 4)
    {
        printf("Missing input arguments\n");
        return -1;
    }

    OPTION = argv[1];
    SIZE   = argv[2];
    NUMBER = argv[3];

    if (strcmp(OPTION,"-b") == 0)
    {
        number = str_to_ull(NUMBER,2);
        print_ull(number,10);
        return 0;
    }

    if (strcmp(OPTION,"-d") == 0)
    {
        number = str_to_ull(NUMBER,10);
        print_ull(number,2);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Invalid input arguments\n");
    return -1;
    }
```

The problem is at  printf("%d",ull%base) on line 20 and the compiler error says---
format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]--- How do I fix this? I'm new to C so I apologize ahead of time if this is a simple solution I'm missing.

Comment: Might want to fix your indentation of the `main()` function... as well as some others.

Comment: `printf("%d",ull%base);` --> `printf("%llu",ull%base);`

Comment: or `printf("%d",(int)(ull%base));`

Comment: @chux That looks to have fixed my compiler errors. Much appreciated